# 動画の拡張子の変換

Tags: php

movファイルをアップロードするときにmp4に変換したいのですが、
phpでアップロードされた動画ファイルの拡張子をa.movからa.mp4にしてアップロードするのでも大丈夫でしょうか？

いろいろ調べてみるとffmpeg?など使用するのが一般的なようですが、簡単に行いたいので、上記の方法で問題がないか、ご教示頂けないでしょうか。

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 3):

アップロード先のサーバが上手く判別してくれない限りは、事前に再エンコードする必要があるかと思います。
※拡張子が違うだけでなく、メタデータや動画データ自体のフォーマット（コーデック）が異なるため

ffmpegはこの再エンコードの作業を行うために使えるプログラムで、それ単体ではコマンドラインで作業する必要があるのですが、GUIで簡単に操作できるようなプログラムもあります。

例えば、有名なのではHandBrakeなどがあります。
https://handbrake.fr/

英語のUIにはなってしまいますが、単に変換するだけであればデフォルトの設定のままでも大丈夫かと思いますので、是非試してみてください。

なお、デフォルトでは恐らく拡張子がmp4、動画コーデックはH.264になっています。H.264は、YouTubeやFacebookなどWebで配信されている動画で広く扱われているフォーマットなので、Web向けであれば、そのまま利用されて問題ないかと思います。

Comment: phpのプログラムで動画の容量を下げることは難しいでしょうか？

Comment: PHP側で動画のエンコードを行うことも可能ですが、実際にはPHPからffmpegなどを操作することになります。PHPからffmpegを操作には、こういったドライバがあります: https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg

Comment: あ、あとPHPからAmazon S3にアップロードしてElastic Transcoderで処理するというのもありそうですね。